# WSO2 Carbon 4.0.1 No Features in Management Console

Tags: wso2

We are installing WSO2 Carbon 4.0.1.  We have the management console setup, but when we add the repository:  http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.1  and click "Find Features" an error occurs: "Error occured while querying installable features."

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share logs printed in the console.? I tried and it worked fine.

Comment: Make sure you aren't behind a proxy.  If I remember correctly, carbon does not support provisioning if you are behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is due to a network failure while connecting to the remote repository. As a workaround you can download the zip form of p2-repo from [here](http://dist.wso2.org/products/carbon/4.0.1/p2-repo.zip).

Unzip it and point it as the p2-repo. (use the option, select repo from local file system when adding the repository)

hth.